# Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() although mbstring is enabled

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, php-7.2, ubuntu-18.04

I have mbstring installed on my Server and it shows in the "Additional .ini files parsed" line in the phpinfo() output.
But when I try to use the `mb_convert_encoding()` function, it gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in /var/www/example.org/public_html/debug.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/example.org/public_html/debug.php on line 11
```

When I try to install mbstring with `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring` it says that mbstring is already installed

Comment: There are two php.ini files, one for cli and one for apache. Ensure the extension is enabled in apache.

Comment: add e.g. `echo in_array('mbstring', get_loaded_extensions()) ? 'mbstring enabled' : 'mbstring missing';` to your debug.php to ensure it really is enabled/loaded where you need it. And check with `php_ini_loaded_file()` which php.ini is used.

Comment: It says mbstring is missing. The used ini file is `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` but when I enable mbstring in this file and restart apache nothing happens

Comment: I don't know why but I tried `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring` again today and it worked. No idea why...